# 'React' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
// tslint:disable
import * as React from 'react';
import { Input, InputProps } from '../atoms/Input/Input';
import { FormControl } from '../hoc/FormControl/FormControl';

export const FormInput = FormControl<InputProps>(Input);
```

Typescript will not compile it but complains:

> 'React' is declared but its value is never read.

If I remove the line I get:

> Exported variable 'FormInput' has or is using name 'React.ComponentClass' from external module "/node_modules/@types/react/index" but cannot be named.
>   [ts] Exported variable 'FormInput' has or is using name 'React.StatelessComponent' from external module "/node_modules/@types/react/index" but cannot be named.

I have `declaration` set to true in tsconfig which is correct as this is a package.

Answer (score 6):

update tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to TypeScript 2.9 or newer.  TypeScript 2.9 adds support for [import types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#import-types), which should make it possible to remove the import of `React` and still generate the declaration file.